# What exactly are these frequency uses mentioned in the FAA's advisory circular on VHF use?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications

The FAA's document AC 90-50, ([currently AC 90-50D](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/23091)) sets forth how the aviation communications frequencies (118.000-136.975) are allocated in the United States.  Many of the assignment designations are plain enough, and common to the understanding of pilots, but some designations are outside normal use, for example:

- Aviation Support
- Domestic VHF
- Flight Test Stations
- Flight Inspection Use

Is there a document which provides descriptions of what these designations are and what qualifies as legitimate use of those frequencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FCC is the ultimate authority on radio frequency usage in the US. [47 CFR § 87.5](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/87.5) has the definitions of the aviation services.

> *Aviation support station.* An aeronautical station used to coordinate aviation services with aircraft and to communicate with
>   aircraft engaged in unique or specialized activities. (See subpart K)

[Subpark K:](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/87.319)

> § 87.319 Scope of service.
>
> Aviation support stations are used for the following types of
>   operations:
>
> (a) Pilot training;
>   (b) Coordination of soaring activities between gliders, tow aircraft
>   and land stations;
>   (c) Coordination of activities between free balloons or
>   lighter-than-air aircraft and ground stations;
>   (d) Coordination between aircraft and aviation service organizations
>   located on an airport concerning the safe and efficient
>   portal-to-portal transit of the aircraft, such as the types of fuel
>   and ground services available; and
>   (e) Promotion of safety of life and property.

*Domestic VHF* use is described in [§ 87.263.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/87.263) In general, these frequencies are used for communicating with aircraft, or between ground stations. There are various restrictions on certain frequencies/ranges, and despite the name, some are allowed for use on international routes.

Back to § 87.5:

> *Flight test aircraft station.* An aircraft station used in the testing
>   of aircraft or their major components.
>
> *Flight test land station.* An aeronautical station used in the testing
>   of aircraft or their major components.

*Flight Inspection* is not defined in § 87.5, so it may be the FAA setting these aside for their own use, but these frequencies are used by the FAA for [ensuring "the integrity of instrument approaches and airway procedures."](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/avn/flightinspection/)